# How to import module in scheme?

Tags: scheme, scheme48

Im new to scheme. I am trying to import module "sorting" in scheme. I tried everything from (load sorting) to (open sorting), (import sorting). I was able to use

```
,open sorting
```

when I am in scheme bash. However I want to import the module to a scheme file. I am using scheme48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the module language.

More details can be found here: http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme48-module-system

Basically, instead of writing just a normal scheme file, foo.scm:

```lisp
;; foo.scm
(define (hello) (display "Hello World!"))
```

You need to use the module language

```lisp
;; foo2.scm

;; this is not scheme, it's the module language
(define-structure hello (export hello)
  (open scheme)
  ;; or others here
  (begin
    ;; this is Scheme
    (define (hello) (display "Hello World!"))))
```

You can learn more about the module language here: http://s48.org/1.8/manual/manual-Z-H-5.html